# Difference between f and &f

Tags: c++, function, c++11, stl

Consider the code:

```
void f(int) {}

int main()
{
    std::function<void(int)>func = f;
    func(3);
    std::function<void(int)>funcc = &f;
    funcc(3);

    void(*ptr)(int) = f;
    ptr(3);
    void(*ptrr)(int) = &f;
    ptrr(3);
}
```

This code compiles successfully and it seems to me like all the calls of `f` are the same. In the first part function is being made a **functor** with wrapping in `std::function` and in the second part I'm using pointers to function.

My main question is: what is the difference between writing `= f;` and `= &f;`? Moreover, what is `&f`? Is it an address of `f`? Or a reference to `f`? I'll highly appreciate any explanations!

Comment: In many cases, just using the name of the function decays into a function pointer. For instance http://stackoverflow.com/q/26559758/1171191

Comment: you also can  write (*ptr)(3), (**ptr)(3), etc. (), always operates on a pointer-to-function. When you write (*p)(), the pointer is dereferenced, and then immediately un-dereferenced again so that the function call operator gets what it wants. Same with f and &f, it gets dereferenced to pointer to function.

Comment: There's no difference, there is implicit conversion from function to pointer-to-function