# Why does casting a struct member to its struct pointer type work?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I'm not sure of the terminology to explain this correctly, but I have isolated the code into a file on it's own to kind of understand how it works, and I'm hoping someone can further help me with this!

The main issues I have understanding this is why does `void (*exec)(struct test_t*);` work exactly? A struct member casts itself as the struct pointer? That is very confusing to me.

Also, in the switch-case statement I understand that in these lines `test.exec = fcn1; test.exec(&test);` the function gets assigned to that struct member and that in the brackets the function parameter gets passed in order for the function to be executed. But how is that set to actually happen in the variable definition?

Am I basically assigning a function to be a struct member? If yes then how does it know about itself before the struct is even compiled? And what is this syntax `(*x)(struct y*)` used for ?

```
typedef struct test_t{
    int num;
    void (*exec)(struct test_t*);
}test_t;

void fcn0(test_t* test);
void fcn1(test_t* test);
void fcn2(test_t* test);

int main(){
    while(1){
        test_t test = {
            .num = 0,
            .exec = fcn0
        };

        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &test.num);

        switch (test.num)
        {
        case 1:
            test.exec = fcn1;
            test.exec(&test);
            break;
        case 2:
            test.exec = fcn2;
            test.exec(&test);
            break;
        
        default:
            test.exec = fcn0;
            test.exec(&test);
            break;
        }

        printf("Value: %d\n", test.num);
    }
}

void fcn0(test_t* test){
    printf("Entered fcn0\n");
    test->num = 0;
}

void fcn1(test_t* test){
    printf("Entered fcn1\n");
    test->num = 1;
}

void fcn2(test_t* test){
    printf("Entered fcn2\n");
    test->num = 2;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/840504/12907698)

Comment: Some aspects of it yes even though the address operator ```&``` isn't needed in my code? I'm guessing the compiler figures it out?

Comment: Correct, `&` is not needed here, one is effectively inserted automatically.  BTW there is no casting in this code.

Comment: [Function-to-function-pointer "decay"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559758/function-to-function-pointer-decay)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
void (*exec)(struct test_t*)
```

Declares `exec` as a **function pointer**.  This pointer points to a function that takes a single parameter of type `struct test_t*` and has a return type of `void`.

When you do this:

```
test.exec = fcn1;
```

The function `fcn1` is first automatically adjusted to a pointer to that function, and that function pointer is assigned to `test.exec`.  This function is declared as `void fcn1(test_t* test);`, so a pointer to this function has the same type as the `exec` member of the struct.

Then when you do this:

```
test.exec(&test);
```

You're executing the function pointed to by `test.exec` and passing it `&test` as a parameter.

Note also that there's no requirement that the parameter passed to this function is `&test` specifically.  It can a pointer to any struct of type `struct test_t`.  This is just a way of emulating a "this" pointer in C similar to how C++ works, but requires the programmer to call functions in a certain way for it to work.

Comment: Thank you! Very insightful! Does this mean that I create a new struct inside the function pointer parameters, so that the compiler is happy?

Comment: @YiannisMichael You're not "creating" a struct.  You're calling the function pointed to by the `exec` member and passing it a parameter.

Comment: So the typedef doesn't exist at that point so I need to specify in those parameters that I will be passing a struct pointer of test_t?

Answer (score 5):

```
void (*exec)(struct test_t*)
```

This makes `exec` a pointer to a `void` function that takes a `struct test_t*` as a parameter .

> ... `test.exec = fcn1; test.exec(&test);` the function gets assigned to that struct member and that in the brackets the function parameter gets passed in order for the function to be executed. But how is that set to actually happen in the variable definition?

- `test.exec` is assigned to point at `fcn1`.
- The pointed out function is then called with `&test` as an argument. It has the same effect as calling the function directly:

  ```c
  fcn1(&test);
  ```